# How to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server from Linux shell?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, sql-server

I have the following problem: I am working on an Ubuntu Linux server (I have access only to the shell, no desktop environment) and I have to interact with a **Microsoft SQL server** to create some tables on a database.

So what I need is a command line client that, from the shell, allow me to connect to this MS SQL Server DB and interact with it.

What can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following url is the answer for your question:
https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: That link is German.  This is the English version:  [Quickstart: Install SQL Server and create a database on Ubuntu](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15).  You may want to see [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) also as it is remote server.

Comment: Ok thanks: only one doubt. I have not to install SQL server on my Linux environment. I only have to connect to an external (remote) MS SQL server. So have I just to install the "SQL Server command-line tools"?

Comment: Yes I think so. Just try it. Learning by doing now you have one more step.