# How do I install MSSql command line tool without using sudo?

Tags: linux, ms-sql

This question points to Microsoft's directions, which require you to use sudo apt-get

I don't have sudo on the machine I need to use the tool from.  how do i simply install the tool?

[How to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server from Linux shell?](https://superuser.com/questions/1506551/how-to-connect-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-from-linux-shell)

Comment: Did you try running the setup as root?  If that does not work then you will have to configure your system to support sudo, if you can't do that, have somebody who can do it.

Comment: what linux distro do you use? apt-get is common on debian-based systems (where Sudo is generally installed by default),  You don't actually need sudo, if you have another means to run a process as root. the other question is whether your distro uses an apt-based package management scheme, or somthing else.

Comment: I don't have root or sudo.  It's RHEL8

Comment: I believe the RHEL uses the YUM package management system rather than `apt`, so I think you need an entirely different guide to help you set it up. and you will likely need assistance from an administrator if you don't have root capability. that guide only covers Ubuntu (though it will probably work for other debian based systems).